# Is this program efficient

Tags: vb.net

I've put together a small calculator application that works quite well, but despite being a novice to VB.net I know that the program probably isn't as efficient as it should be. The idea is that upon inputting numbers into a textbox and pressing a mathematical operator, the textbox will reset and continue the equation, storing the past values entered.

```
    Dim input1 As Double
Dim numfunction As Double
'numerical functions (null = 0, add = 1, subtract = 2, divide = 3, multiply = 4)
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    If txtNum.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a number")
    Else
        numfunction = 1
        input1 = input1 + txtNum.Text
        txtNum.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnEqual_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnEqual.Click
    If txtNum.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a final number")
    End If

    If numfunction = 1 Then
        txtNum.Text = txtNum.Text + input1
        input1 = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Could you point me in the right direction as to what I should replace add or remove to make my programs more efficient in the future? Keep in mind that the BtnAdd_Click event is just one of 4 (add, sub, divide, multiply) and because of that btnEqual_Click will have a few if statements, checking for what function the user has put in, and if there is anything in txtNum at all.

Thanks in advance, I'm not asking for anyone to complete my code, but I'd love to see what options I have so I make more efficient programs in the future.

Comment: You are going to want to turn Option Strict On, as a start ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Comment: You are making a traditional mistake, you demand to know how to make the code faster but won't tell us *how much* faster it needs to be.  Because you have no idea whatsoever, you didn't actually *measure* how fast the code is right now.  Use the Stopwatch class.  And after you obtained the measurement, contemplate if it really matters that the user sees the result in the fraction of a microsecond it takes now or 20 milliseconds.  He can't tell the difference.  In other words, your code is already a *million* times faster than it needs to be.  Kinda pointless, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little initial effort you could simplify this task by using the power of object oriented programming:

```
Public Class Form1
    ' hold a reference to all operations in a list of operations
    Private _operations As New List(Of Operation)

    ' the operation currently choosen
    Private Property _currentOperation As Operation

    ' the 2 numbers you want to perform the operations on
    Private _number1 As Double = 0
    Private _number2 As Double = 0

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        SetupOperations()
        TextBox1.Text = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeOperation(operation As Operation)
        _number1 = _currentOperation.FunctionDelegate.Invoke(_number1, _number2)
        TextBox1.Text = _number1
        _currentOperation = operation
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetupOperations()
        _operations.Add(New Operation(Me, btnAdd, Function(x, y)
                                                      Return x + y
                                                  End Function))
        ' heres the crux ... you use anonymous method to define your functions hook them to the form (Me) and the related Button
        ' all at once
        ' Similar for the other operations (subtract / multiply / divide / pow, and so on)


        Dim equalsOperation As New Operation(Me, btnEqual, Function(x, y)
                                                               Return y
                                                           End Function)
        _operations.Add(equalsOperation)
        _currentOperation = equalsOperation
    End Sub

    ' for this example i used only one textbox and a lable indicating wheter the number entered is a valid double
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim result As Double
        If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, result) Then
            _number2 = result
            lblValid.Text = "Valid" ' tell the user that the number entered is valid or not
        Else
            lblValid.Text = "Invalid"
        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' An Operation that hooks up a button click and can execute the operation
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class Operation
        Private _owningForm As Form1
        Public Property FunctionDelegate As Func(Of Double, Double, Double) ' use a delegate to a Func that returns double with 2 double parameters

        Public Sub New(owningForm As Form1, boundButton As Button, functionDelegate As Func(Of Double, Double, Double))
            Me.FunctionDelegate = functionDelegate
            Me._owningForm = owningForm
            AddHandler boundButton.Click, AddressOf boundButton_Click ' make the operation hook up on the click event
        End Sub

        Private Sub boundButton_Click()
            _owningForm.ChangeOperation(Me)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

Hope this is not too confusing for you, I intended to show you a bigger world than simple routines and tons of eventhandlers

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code by inserting your checking code into a separate subroutine.

```
Sub CheckVals()
If txtNum.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a final number")
End If

If numfunction = 1 Then
    txtNum.Text = txtNum.Text + input1
    input1 = 0
End If
End Sub
```

You would then reference this sub from your two button click events.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
CheckVals()
End Sub
```